# What is a good solution for cross browser javascript redirect with history?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I am currently fighting Google Chrome on the following action:

```
location.href = url
```

---

```
location.replace(url)
```

---

```
document.location = url
```

---

```
window.navigate(url) // doesn't work in Chrome/Firefox
```

---

```
location.assign(url)
```

---

```
window.open(url, '_self')
```

---

```
window.location.href = url
```

---

I have tried all, and neither will add a history entry.  Is there a way in Google Chrome to do a javascript redirect WITH history?

Thanks.

---

**Explanation**
We have a table of items, when clicking on the row, I want the page to navigate to a specified URL, if anyone has a good solution to this other than using the onclick=send method we are using now, please let me know.

---

**Update**
It appears that Stackoverflow its-self has this exact same issue. In the main view, click on one of the first 3 columns in the question list (# answers, etc..), then click the back button, it will take you back 2 pages.

Comment: I edited my answer.  Please try it.

Comment: Also, Chrome behaves correctly for me.  It goes back, as expected.

Comment: I will give this a small try today, see if it is easy to implement with a jquery solution.

Comment: The form method didn't work as well.

Comment: Did you take a look into your history (*History* menu, *Show History*)?

Comment: I did, and it does not show up at all in Chrome.

Comment: This is an issue with Chrome 2, not Chrome 3 (devchannel)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although, I first must say that this is Chrome behaving stupid, and you probably should not worry about it.  Try to create a dummy form and with a GET method and programmatically submit it...

```
<form id="dummyForm" method="GET" action="#">
  <input type="hidden" name="test" value="test" />
</form>
```

Then your onclick...

```
var frm = document.forms["dummyForm"];
frm.action = url;
frm.submit();
```

Comment: see my answer, but i basically took this method and it worked out great, thanks!

Comment: I know it's far from an ideal solution, but I am glad it worked out for you!

Comment: This kind of redirect did not work for me in Firefox 13.0.1, using JQuery 1.7.1 and the following code: `$('<form id="dummyForm" method="GET" action="/content/application-submit.php"> <input type="hidden" name="application" value="success" /></form>').submit();`. However, it works if you use something like: `$('<form id="dummyForm" method="GET" action="/content/application-submit.php"> <input type="hidden" name="application" value="success" /></form>').appendTo('body'); document.getElementById('dummyForm').submit();`.

Comment: I.e., you cannot use this to redirect in Firefox unless it's actually in the document.

Comment: @JoshStodola After I tested it. It works fine in IE8 and Chrome, but the redirected url end with a unnecessary question mark, How to remove it ?thanks.

Answer (score 2):

all javascript solution based on @Josh Stodola answer

```
function goTo(url, data){
    var ele_form = document.createElement("FORM");
    ele_form.method = "POST";
    ele_form.id = 'dummy_form';
    ele_form.action = url;
    if (!!data){
        for(key in data){
            var dummy_ele = document.createElement('INPUT');
            dummy_ele.name = key;
            dummy_ele.value = data[key];
            dummy_ele.type = 'hidden';
            ele_form.appendChild(dummy_ele);
        }
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].append(ele_form);
    document.getElementById('dummy_form').submit();
}
```

Comment: Hi, rbawaskar, After I tested it. It works fine in IE8 and Chrome, but the redirected url end with a unnecessary question mark, How to remove it ?thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question, but if you're navigating to a link on the same page, you should be able to simply do the following, where 123 is the item id:

```
window.location = "items/123";
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do using jQuery is something like:

```
$("table tbody td").wrapInner('<a href="myurl.htm?id=' + getTheIDSomehow + '"></a>');
```

Since I don't know the structure of your markup it's difficult to provide a more specific fix.

See the [jQuery documentation on wrapInner](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrapInner#html).

Answer (score 0):

What about "clicking" a link with JS?

```
<a href="/url.html" id="clickme">blah blah</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clickme').click();
});
</script>
```

I'm not sure if this work, but it should mimic a user clicking the link.

Comment: I realize this is an ancient answer, but I believe the `.click()` will only trigger any `click` events registered on the `a` tag. I could be wrong. I had a problem recently where that didn't work and I had to use `jquery.simulate.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking what Josh Stodola recommended, and doing it with jquery instead, I have created a method that seems to get around this Chrome issue without a lot of overhead in the markup.

Here is a fully working version.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Row Navigation with History</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font: 14px Georgia, serif;
    }

    #page-wrap {
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    table {
        border-collapse:collapse;
        width:100%;
    }
    thead {
        text-align:left;
        font: 16px serif;
    }
    tbody {
        font: 14px Georgia, serif;
    }

    tr {
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding:10px;
    }

    .slim {
        width:88px;
    }

    .wide {
        width:300px;
    }

    .hover {
        background-color:#eee;
    }

</style>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $("td").hover(function() {
            $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
        }, function() {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
        });


        $("tr").click(function() {
            if (navigator.userAgent.toString().indexOf("Chrome/2") != -1)
            {
                var form = $("<form></form>");
                form.attr("method", "get");
                form.attr("action", $(this).attr("rel"));
                form.submit();
            } else {
                location.href = $(this).attr("rel");
            }
        });
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">
<table>
    <colgroup />
    <colgroup class="wide" />
    <colgroup class="slim" />
    <colgroup class="slim" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr rel="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173912/what-is-a-good-solution-for-cross-browser-javascript-redirect-with-history">
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>1/1/2009</td>
            <td>Available</td>
        </tr>
        <tr rel="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>1/1/2009</td>
            <td>Available</td>
        </tr>
        <tr rel="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>1/1/2009</td>
            <td>Available</td>
        </tr>
        <tr rel="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>1/1/2009</td>
            <td>Available</td>
        </tr>
        <tr rel="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>1/1/2009</td>
            <td>Available</td>
        </tr>
        <tr rel="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>1/1/2009</td>
            <td>Available</td>
        </tr>
        <tr rel="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>1/1/2009</td>
            <td>Available</td>
        </tr>
        <tr rel="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>1/1/2009</td>
            <td>Available</td>
        </tr>
        <tr rel="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>1/1/2009</td>
            <td>Available</td>
        </tr>
        <tr rel="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>1/1/2009</td>
            <td>Available</td>
        </tr>
        <tr rel="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>1/1/2009</td>
            <td>Available</td>
        </tr>
        <tr rel="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>1/1/2009</td>
            <td>Available</td>
        </tr>
        <tr rel="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>1/1/2009</td>
            <td>Available</td>
        </tr>
        <tr rel="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>1/1/2009</td>
            <td>Available</td>
        </tr>
        <tr rel="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>1/1/2009</td>
            <td>Available</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

chrome is not supported location.reload. Use window.open(url, '_self') for page redirect

Comment: That actually doesn't add to history either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice functional and clean jQuery solution based on Josh Stodola's (which didn't work for me).

```
function redirect(url, data) {
    var form = $('<form method="get"></form>');
    form.attr("action", url);

    for (key in data){
        var input = $('<input type="hidden"/>');

        input.attr("name", key);
        input.attr("value", data[key]);

        form.append(input);
    }

    $("body").append(form);

    $(form)[0].submit();
}
```